# How to retrieve the coordinate information of a specified dbId based on Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

```
viewer.getProperties
```

The information obtained is limited. How to obtain its coordinate information or information corresponding to the "list" command in CAD software?

Answer (score 0):

viewer.getProperties only returns the properties of key-value. Viewer provides triangles(mesh) of the object. It does not have a kind of data of coordination like original design software. This blog tells how to get the data of mesh:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/show-mesh-triangles-data-hittest

you could also get boundingbox of the object, as a reference of the position. In one demo of this blog below, it tells how to get boundingbox
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer